# get_option() fails to return binary result

Tags: api

For some reason, `get_option()` started to fail when returning binary results when I moved my website from localhost to the web server. I migrated my WordPress using an upload of the files on the FTP

Everything else works perfectly however. Even the `wp-admin` works right: I can edit, post, etc. It's just a single line of code that is giving me the blues. It comes from a theme I'm using, but there is no theme-specific behavior: it crashes way before that. That line of code tries to do this:

```
$sqbtn_1 = unserialize(get_option('magaling_ads_468060_1')); //returns null.
$sqbtn_1 = $sqbtn_1->is_empty() ? $ad_def : $sqbtn_1;  //CRASHES: is_empty on a non-object.
```

If I create a simple PHP file, I can prove myself that the data comes correctly from MySQL. I have the 'magaling_ads_468060_1' field in my WordPress options table and here is what it contains:

```
mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8');
$result = mysql_query("select * from wp_options WHERE option_name = 'magaling_ads_468060_1'");
//prints out the following value of the option_value field:
s:376:"O:18:"Padd_Advertisement":5:{s:27:"Padd_Advertisementimg_url";s:88:"http://www.echysttas.org/wp-content/themes/magaling/images/advertisement-468x060_1.jpg";s:28:"Padd_Advertisementalt_desc";s:15:"Axonn Echysttas";s:27:"Padd_Advertisementweb_url";s:24:"http://www.echysttas.org";s:26:"Padd_Advertisementtarget";s:4:"_new";s:29:"Padd_Advertisementcss_class";s:0:"";}";
```

So the MySQL returns the data! However, get_option returns **nothing**. I echo-ed it and it's empty. On the other side...

```
get_option('magaling_installed'); //works and returns "1"
```

Everything else works fine, even returning other theme-specific (integer or string) values.

```
var_dump( get_option('magaling_ads_468060_1') ); //shows bool(false) 
var_dump( get_option('magaling_installed') ); //shows string(1) "1" 
var_dump( get_option('blogname') ); //string(9) "Echysttas"
```

Comment: Add more info regarding the actual problem and show how the output differs from your expectations. On a side note, Options API handle serialization and unserialization for you, you need not mess with that. What does `var_dump( get_option('magaling_ads_468060_1') );` show?

Comment: I added more data. I hope it helps.

Comment: Found the problem. Had to answer my own question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem. And **A WORD OF WARNING to people MIGRATING their WordPress Installations**. Read this to understand how get_option is going to start failing when `unserializing` binary data from the DB.

What I did was to migrate my WordPress the hardcore way: copy all files to the web server, restore the full SQL database script.

Prior to the restore, I did a mass replace in the SQL database to change the URLs from local to web server. And that's where the problem lies.

There were PHP serialized objects in the database. Where a string is serialized, its length is prepended. And, you can guess the clusterfuck I got myself into: since I mass-replaced the host-name, I should have modified string lengths of serialized objects everywhere I had serialized host names.

Using a default WordPress installation this would not be a problem because WordPress doesn't use such features. But if you use Plugins or Themes and you use this method for migrating your blog, you're asking for problems.

Luckily I have very few formerly-local URLs inside serialized objects, only two, to be precise.

I hope my 7 hours of battle with this problem will serve somebody.

Comment: Obviously you shouldn't modify serialized data. The only thing you need to change for moving your site is the site URL and home URL. If you want to change the links, then replace them in post content. I guess you were saving local URLs in options somewhere. Remember `print_r()` & `var_dump()` are your friends